# how different between $_GET and $request->getParameter()

Tags: frameworks, parameters, symfony1

I'm currently studing symfony framework.
and I could not found the answer of how different between `$_GET` and `$request->getParameter()`.
I can understand the $request->getPrameter() can be used for,

```
if(isset($_GET['test'])){
 $test = $_GET['test'];
}else{
 $test = 'Unknown';
}
```

to

```
$request->getParameter('test','Unknown');
```

and anything else? I was expect it filter XSS but I think it doesn't.

For me, `$_GET` way is much easier, but I feel like I should use the `$request->getParameter()`

So, I'd like to know exactly how diffrence.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$request['parameter']
```

This is equivalent to `$request->getParameter('parameter', null)`.

Note that `$request->getParameter` differs from `$_GET` in that it returns all parameter types. `$request->getGetParameter` is equivalent to `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

If you access a request parameter like:

```
$request->getParameter('parameter');
```

it can be the value of $_GET['parameter'] or $_POST['parameter'] as well. It is useful as normally you don't care whether the value is coming through post or get method.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** infact be using `$request->getGetParameter('parameter')` if you're specifically after a get parameters.

`$request->getGetParameter('parameter')` is the equivalent of `$_REQUEST['parameter']` which may not result in the desired behaviour.

Also worth noting that the sfWebRequest object is available in your views via `$sf_request` i.e. `$sf_request->getGetParameter('parameter')`